# Create ListViewItem based on ComboBox SelectedItem in MVVM

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, combobox, selecteditem

I have a `StackPanel` that contain a `ComboBox` and several other controls like `Label` and `TextBox`(not shown in the example below).

I would like to add several other controls to the end of that`StackPanel` based on the user selected item from the `ComboBox`.

Example:
If my `ComboBox` ItemSource consist of: Square, Rectangle, Circle etc.
Then upon selecting of a shape the proper ListViewItem Will be shown and a new set of controls will be visiable, for Square the `Label` will be "Side:"
and for Circle the `Label` will be "Radius:".

At start:

[image]

After user select Square

[image]

After user select Circle

[image]

I'm not sure if using the ListViewItem is the right way to go, and if it is, how to accomplish that (In MVVM).

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have about 16 different rows, so creating each row and adding all the labels and text boxes to each selected item and play with the visibility of the items is something that I want to avoid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding controls dynamically. You can have all the controls predefined in the xaml and depends on your shape selection the visibility of such controls can be changed as well as your labels content.

Comment: Yes, I know.
I prefer to use a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the PropertyGrid control in the free "Xceed WPF Toolkit", available via NuGet. (stay away from the "vanilla" .Net PropertyGrid as it has some issues with MVVM).

The PropertyGrid renders a list-based UI that looks very like the Visual Studio "properties" window, allowing a user to edit the values of one or more properties (of different types).

It's been a while since I used it but you would typically create a class for each shape, with the relevant properties, e.g.

```
public class Square
{
    [Category("Main")]
    [DisplayName("Side length")]
    public int Side {get; set;}
}

public class Circle
{
    [Category("Main")]
    [DisplayName("Circle radius")]
    public int Radius {get; set;}
}
```

When you select an item in the combobox, you could instantiate the relevant type of object (Square, Circle) and assign it to a property on your VM (making sure to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` stuff). This could be of type 'object', or some common interface. You bind this property to the PropertyGrid control's `SelectedObject` property.

There are various custom attributes that you can decorate your class properties with to control their appearance in the property grid control, e.g. category, display name, whether or not to include the property in the grid, etc. Documentation is fairly basic on their free page (https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/PropertyGrid) but with a bit of googling you can find more detailed docs from their "paid" version, e.g. https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes_namespace.html